# Web scraping using Python and Beautiful soup: error "'page' is not defined"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From a betting [site](http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/fr-fr), I want to collect the betting rates. After inspecting the page, I noticed that these rates were included into a *eventprice* class. Following the explanation from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-and-exploring-sports-betting-data-is-arbitrage-possible-a-hands-on-analysis-with-code-2ba656d7f5b), I thus wrote this code in Python, using Beautifulsoup module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/fr-fr"

try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
    print("An error occured.")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

regex = re.compile('eventprice')
content_lis = soup.find_all('button', attrs={'class': regex})
print(content_lis)
```

However, I got the following error:

> "(...) line 12, in 
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') NameError: name 'page' is not defined"

Comment: well, if the `try` won’t be successful, than `page` won’t be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the exception details you will see what is happening:

```
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Output

```
An error occurred: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 12, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'page' is not defined
```

urlopen() is raising an Exception which results in an undefined 'page' variable.
In this case it's a 403 which means you may need to add authentication in order to access this URL.

Update:

A 403 response means there is no way to access this URL in the way that you are trying to access it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by 'add authentification'?

Comment: If the problem were authentication, that would typically be a 401 response, not 403.

Comment: The betting server is returning an HTTP 403 status, which the meaning is detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403. I think as opposed to a 401 a 403 means there is no way to access the URL you are trying in the way you are trying it. Interestingly enough, I tried with curl and it returned a 200 instead. I was able to get the 403 again by adding -H "User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.9".  It looks like they are filtering based on User-Agent strings in order to block people scraping their website.