# Web scraping using Python and Selenium: looking for ways to speed up my code (very slow and inefficient now)

Tags: python, selenium

As a beginner in Python and Selenium, I tried to write my own script to scrape data from a betting site ([Winamax](https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/7)) and save it into a dataset. My script uses the `find_elements_by_tag_name('div')` function of the Selenium module in order to find all elements with the `div` tag name. Searching for `div` rather than `scan` (as it was first recommended, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509322/web-scraping-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-what-is-saved-by-the-beautifulsoup-f)) is more convenient in my case, as one element of the resulting list gathers all the information of the table that I need. I basically need the date of the game (which is at the beginning of the element, e.g. *MERCREDI 6 JANVIER*), the teams (e.g. *Brest-Nice*), the three betting rates per game and the time of the game. Here is a printscreen of a part of the table:

[image: Picture of the table]

And here is the dataframe that I want to obtain:
[image: Data frame of the betting odds]
The downside of this approach is that there are a lot of `div` tags, which makes my code very slow and inefficient. Based on my code below, is there any way to speed up my code, while keeping the same resulting string list?

I included a few `print()` in my code to see all the elements with `div` tag. The model without the print takes approximatively 2 minutes, and 4 minutes with the prints.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time

start = time.time()

#Load script from website
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.binary_location = r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

end1 = time.time()

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe', options=option)
browser.get(r"https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/7/4")

end2 = time.time()

#Select the part of the script where data are stored
span_tags = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')

end25 = time.time()

tags = []
for span_tag in span_tags:
    tags.append(span_tag.text)
    print(span_tag.text)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
print(len(tags))

end3 = time.time()

#Select the element of the list that describe the data we need
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:LUNDI|MARDI|MERCREDI|JEUDI|VENDREDI|SAMEDI|DIMANCHE)')
my_list5 = list(filter(pattern.match,tags))

#Print the indices of the selected element
print([i for i, j in enumerate(tags) if pattern.match(j)])

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#Print the selected element
for m in my_list5:
    print(m)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")

#Select the first element, as it gathers all the necessary information
string=my_list5[0]
string2=string.splitlines()

#Print the executing times between the different tasks
print(end1-start)
print(end2-end1)
print(end25-end2)
print(end3-end25)
```

Comment: What exact information do you want to retrieve from the site? From your code it seems that you're printing the code from all the `span` elements on the page but i'm unsure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I updated my question: I need the date, the time, the teams and the betting rates.

Answer (score 0):

```
        import datetime

        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

        url = 'https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/7/4'

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='venv/chromedriver-Darwin', options=options)

        driver.get(url)
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
    
        # get all divs containing the day and teams
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        teams_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class=\'ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer\']/div')))
    
        # declare the current day
        current_day = ''
        try:
            for elem in teams_elements:
                if len(elem.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sc-plgXW.lfShEr')) == 1:
                    print('============================================================================')
                    # if the current div is actually a day displayed, update the variable and use it until the next one is found
                    current_day = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-plgXW.lfShEr').text
                else:
                    # get playing teams text
                    playing_teams = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-prPLn.bKrOhT').text
    
                    # get playing hour text
                    playing_hour = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-qQlyE.jlXdeO').text
    
                    # get the betting odds 
                    odds = elem.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sc-pKLCU.WflrK button')
    
                    odds_string = ''
                    # for each odd print the odd value (1,2 or N) and the actual odd
                    for odd_elem in odds:
                        odd_number = odd_elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-qPIWj.cQreJJ').text
                        odd_value = str(odd_elem.text).split('\n')[0]
                        odds_string += f'{odd_number} - {odd_value}; '
    
                    print(f'Day: {current_day} \n'
                          f'Teams playing: {playing_teams} \n'
                          f'Time: {playing_hour} \n'
                          f'Odds: {odds_string}'
                          f'\n')
        except:
            pass
    
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(f'It took: {(end-start).seconds} seconds')

        driver.quit()
```

Tried adding comments to everything, hopefully is making it clearer.

This should display the data like this:

```
============================================================================
Day: MERCREDI 6 JANVIER 
Teams playing: Brest - Nice 
Time: 20:00 
Odds: 1 - 2,15; N - 3,65; 2 - 3,10; 

Day: MERCREDI 6 JANVIER 
Teams playing: Lorient - Monaco 
Time: 20:00 
Odds: 1 - 4,40; N - 4,10; 2 - 1,75; 

#the rest of them here

============================================================================
Day: SAMEDI 9 JANVIER 
Teams playing: Paris SG - Brest 
Time: 22:00 
Odds: 1 - 1,16; N - 8,25; 2 - 16;
```

And timing wise, the last `print()` says:

```
It took: 3 seconds
```

NOTE:
It doesn't take into account the `PARIS SUR LA COMPÉTITION` section, however if you need that as well, it should be pretty easy to update the code to get that as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Cosmin! I tried your script and it is working well, but strangely, it takes about 24 seconds on my pc. Is it because you're printing the values? Ideally, I would like to save them in a pandas data frame (I updated my question, where I included a print screen of the data frame I would like to obtain).

Comment: There could be multiple factor as for the difference between our timings (e.g. hardware and, depending where you get the start time, the network).
As for the data saving, as long as you're able to get to get it successfully from the page, it's just a matter of manipulating by your requirements and saving it wherever you need.
If you need further help with pandas, please open a new focused question here, as I haven't played with it and wouldn't be able to advise there.

Comment: Reading your comment again, the difference in timings could be caused by connections to your data source.
However I would suggest to cache the data (e.g. use an array of objects) and only save it at the end. This way you you will opening and closing a connection to the datasource (pandas) only once and not for every row of games on the page. This will indeed considerably increase the amount it takes to run everything.